# Flex 1056: "Cannot create property" -- but the property already exists in datatable

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3, apache-flex, referenceerror

I'm following a flex application tutorial, and while I've been able to fix most of my errors, this one has me completely stumped.

I have a datatable called employees, with these columns: id, Firstname, Lastname, Title, Birthday, Cellphone, Officephone, Email, Address, photofile.

The application is simple: list all the employees in the HomeView, and when you tap on an employee, takes you to DetailView where you see all their extra info. Every time I do, however, I get: 
"ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property Address on valueObjects.Employees."

Here's the code for DetailView:

```
    xmlns:employeesservice1="services.employeesservice1.*"
    overlayControls="false" 
    title="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Firstname} {getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Lastname}"
    viewActivate="view1_viewActivateHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        protected function goBack(event:Event):void
        {
            navigator.pushView(EmployeeListerHomeView);
        }

        protected function getEmployeesByID(itemID:int):void
        {
            getEmployeesByIDResult.token = employeesService1.getEmployeesByID(itemID);
        }

        protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            this.addElement(busyIndicator);
            getEmployeesByID(data as int);
        }
        protected function getAllEmployeesResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            this.removeElement(busyIndicator);
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getEmployeesByIDResult" result="getAllEmployeesResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
    <employeesservice1:EmployeesService1 id="employeesService1"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button id="backBtn" click="goBack(event)">
        <s:icon>
            <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('assets/save160.png')"
                                    source240dpi="@Embed('assets/save240.png')"
                                    source320dpi="@Embed('assets/save320.png')"/>
        </s:icon>
    </s:Button>
</s:navigationContent>
<s:Image x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
         source="http://localhost/EmployeeLister/assets/{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.photofile}128x128.png" />
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="10" paddingLeft="120">
    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" paddingTop="10" text="Title"/>
    <s:Label text="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Title}"/>
    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" paddingTop="10" text="Cell Phone"/>
    <s:Label text="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Cellphone}"/>
    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" paddingTop="10" text="Office Phone"/>
    <s:Label text="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Officephone}"/>
    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" paddingTop="10" text="Email"/>
    <s:Label text="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Email}"/>
    <s:Label fontWeight="bold" paddingTop="10" text="Address"/>
    <s:Label text="{getEmployeesByIDResult.lastResult.Address}"/>
</s:VGroup>
<s:BusyIndicator id="busyIndicator" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" symbolColor="red"/>
```

Now something to note: I added the Cellphone, Officephone, Email, and Address columns *after* I had created the EmployeesService1, and so I had to edit the .php to include these new values. So I'm worried I might have done something wrong there, but I triple checked for typos and I'm not getting any errors on the other values, so, I don't know. Again, this has me pretty frustrated. I've tested all the operations in the service, and they're all returning all of the appropriate values.

Here's the function from the .php:
    public function getEmployeesByID($itemID) {

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename where id=?");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);        
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->Firstname, $row->Lastname, $row->Title, $row->Birthday, $row->Cellphone, $row->Officephone, $row->Email, $row->Address, $row->photofile);

    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $row->Birthday = new DateTime($row->Birthday);
      return $row;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Even if you don't know the exact answer, are there easier ways for me to figure out what's happening? The call-stack in the error window is all the internal flex/as3 stuff. So I don't want to go down that rabbit hole if I don't have to.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Off: My name is strange but you won!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem was in the .php, after each of the generated `getEmployeesBy**()` functions, there's a `@return stdClass`.

I needed to create a `getEmployeesByName` function, however, and did so in between the `getEmployeesByID()` and the `@return stdClass`. So I just put in another `@return` between the functions and it's all working cleanly now.